# Centering text in \parbox

Tags: tables, boxes

I used `\parbox` to auto-wrap the text, but it should be centered. How can I do?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cW{5}W{5}}
        \toprule
        & {\bf Cost} & {\bf Benefit}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{\bf Social} & Possible land competition & Less air pollution \\
                                & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{5cm}{Possible increase of extraction of wood from forest}} & Less medical expenses \\
                                & & More labour available \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end {table}
```

Comment: try `\parbox{5cm}{\centering Possible increase of extraction of wood from forest}`

Comment: Where is the `W` column type defined?

Comment: There is no need to use parbox here you can simply specify a width instead of `*` to multirow and it will use a `p` column.   You shouldn't be using `\bf` in latex (it is not defined by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making the markup far more complicated than needed (and please always make your examples complete so people can run them) Something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.9cm}}}
\toprule
& \bfseries Cost & \bfseries Benefit\\
\midrule
\bfseries Social
& 
Possible land competition 

Possible increase of extraction of wood from forest
& 
Less air pollution 

Less medical expenses

More labour available \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end {table}

\end{document}
```